# why qml virtualkeyboard is not show after click on edit text ,while I call plugin in .pro and main.cpp

Tags: c++, qt, qml, virtual-keyboard

I use open source qt5.9 for an embedded device.
I wanna to use virtual keyboard in my qml project. I know I should add a static link in .pro file like :

```
static {
    QT += svg
    QTPLUGIN += qtvirtualkeyboardplugin
}
```

and also add

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));

    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    return app.exec();
}
```

to main.cpp file to use the virtual keyboard. but my virtual keyboard does not fire when I click on my text object:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.1

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

        TextInput {
            id: textInput;
            text:"ssssss"
            height: 120;
            width: parent.width - 2;
            anchors.bottom: keyboard.top
            color: "#000000"; // black

            // http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputmethod.html#properties
            focus: Qt.inputMethod.visible;

            verticalAlignment: TextInput.AlignVCenter;
        }
}
```

Comment: "why qml virtualkeyboard is not fire" what do you expect? someone call the fire brigade if it *is fire*?

Comment: it does not show when I tap(touch) in my text edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It solved.
just put the kind of input for each lineedit . like this :

```
InputPanel{
        id:inputpanel
        visible:active
        y:active?parent.height - inputpanel.height : parent.height
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right

    }
    TextInput{
        id:input
        inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
        focus: Qt.inputMethod.visible;
        text: "123211"

    }
    TextInput{
        id:input2
        anchors.top:input.bottom
        inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhLowercaseOnly
        focus: Qt.inputMethod.visible;
        text: "123211"

    }
```